# How do I find all the bases which $11^2 < 122$ is correct for them?

Tags: number-systems

I tried to go all over the bases but it doesn't work well. I don't know how to present multiplying in general...
I believe I somehow have to compute 11 times 11 in every base and convert it to decimal number and check if it bigger than 122.
Any thoughts?

Comment: The bases should be $r>2$ because $2$ is a digit. We also must have $r^2+2r+1=(r+1)^2<r^2+2r+2$, which is equivalent to $0<1$. So all bases $r>2$ are good.

Comment: The multiplication algorithm in any basis can be implemented by convolution with carry and the largest scalar resulting from the convolution $[1,1] * [1,1] = [1,2,1]$ is $2$ which won't overflow and cause carry for any $r>2$. But for $r=2$ we have $11_2 = 3$, $3^2 = 1001$ which we see has overflowed since it has more digits.

Answer (score 1):

If the basis is greater than two, then
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
&1&1\\
\times&1&1\\
\hline
&1&1\\
1&1\\
\hline
1&2&1
\end{array}$$